# monodevelop program hangs on readline

Tags: linux, monodevelop, console.readline

I saw many questions on SO like "Readline gets ignored" but My problem is different.

I have this simple program :

```
using System;
namespace test
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }
}
```

Simple isn't it ? when I execute it using monodevelop I get this :
[image: program output]

As you can see it doesn't matter how many lines I put.

Ctrl+C doesn't work, nor Ctrl+D(end-of-file character on my linux ;) )

I have mono 4.4.0, strange when I execute the above program using `mono program.exe` it works as expected.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806326/monodevelop-on-ubuntu-console-readline-doesnt-work) question So I went to Options -> Run -> General and I have execute program on external console checked.

I saw other questions like "program hangs on Readline" but they talk about `ReadLine` for other streams, I'm talking about the simple `Console.Readline()`.

I have monodevelop 6.0.1 on Arch linux(installed from monodevelop-stable AUR package if that matters).